# Java: How to sort part of a 3d array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have this array: `array[2][7][2]`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        syso(array[i][j][0] + " ");
    }
    syso("/n");
}
```

Currently the above code prints out:

`4 1 2 5 9 0 1`

`2 3 1 9 9 3 1`

Is there a way to have these sorted somehow? I don't really care about `array[i][j][1]`, only about `array[i][j][0]`.

I wrote myself a QuickSort function but obviously this random piece of code doesn't work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    quickSort(array[i][0], 0, array[i].length - 1);     
}
```

*EDIT:*

Here's my QuickSort function as well:

```
static int partition(int a[], int l, int r) {
    int pivot = a[r];
    int k=l-1;

    for(int i=l; i <= r; i++) {
        if (a[i] <= pivot) {
            k++;

            int w = a[i];
            a[i] = a[k];
            a[k] = w;
        }
    }
    return k;
}

static void quickSort(int [] a, int l, int r) {
    if (l>=r) {
        return ;
    }

    int k = partition(a, l, r);
    quickSort(a, l, k-1);
    quickSort(a, k+1, r);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sorting" applied to 2d array? How desired result should look like?

Comment: So that the outputs from the code I wrote become `0 1 1 2 4 5 9` and `1 1 2 3 3 9 9` repectively. Not sure how to explain it otherwise.

Comment: if it is not expensive (array not very large), copy `[i][j][0]` to `another` 2d array and apply `for (int[] a : another) {Arrays.sort(a);}`

Comment: Thanks, @SashaSalauyou , I will eventually probably do that but it will require my to rewrite quite a lot of code. Isn't there another way? I editted my OP with my QuickSort function as well. Can it be modified or something?

Comment: No you cant unless you write special sorting method that uses 3d array. `array[i][0]` doesn't mean "take i-th row from array that is projection of 0th  elements in third dimension", it means "take 0th row of i-th layer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[][] another = int[2][7];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
      anotner[i][j] = array[i][j][0];
   }
}
for (int[] a : anotner) {
    Arrays.sort(a);
}
```

then print `anotner` as you do using `syso()`.

Comment: Will try that, thanks! Isn't there a way to modify the original array itself, though? It would be preferable, by far!

Comment: Simply no and I explained why in the comment. You cannot just simply "swap" dimensions.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Can I dispose of the previous array btw? Or the Garbage Collector takes care of that by itself?

Comment: It will after the initial array gets out of visibility scope and no other references to it remains.